# Unknown column 'tbcontractItems.qtyContracted_int' in 'field list

Tags: mysql

I keep getting this error ( Unknown column 'tbcontractItems.qtyContracted_int' in 'field list ) when I try to create a view in MySQL. The table an columns exists in my database.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW vws_productQtyOnContract AS
SELECT CASE
         WHEN (SUM(tbcontractItems.qtyContracted_int) -
              SUM(tbcontractItems.currReceiptQty_int)) < 0 THEN
          0
         ELSE
          (SUM(tbcontractItems.qtyContracted_int) -
          SUM(tbcontractItems.currReceiptQty_int))
       END AS TotalContractQty_int,
       tbContractItems.productOID
  FROM tbContract
 INNER JOIN tbContractItems
    ON tbContract.transactID = tbContractItems.FK_ID
 WHERE (tbContract.posted_bol = 1)
   AND (tbContractItems.completed_bol <> 1)
 GROUP BY tbContractItems.productOID;
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: MySQL doesn't use T-SQL. Please don't add tags that aren't relevant to the question.

Comment: The error is telling you the problem though, seems your table `qtyContracted_int` doesn't have a column `qtyContracted_int`.

Comment: Add your schema here, so that we can investigate. You might have typo to write column name in the query

Comment: @Larnu thanks - I ran out of tags. lol. After maintaining the sentence CASE on the the table names, the query executed successfully i.e. I wasn't aware of the MySQL database-engine variants that are case-sensitive.

Comment: *"I ran out of tags"* What do you mean? Only tag what's relevant to your question. The only tag that *was* relevant was MySQL, so the others weren't needed. You only *need* one tag. [tag:field], which you tagged, isn't even related to SQL.

Comment: @Larnu OK I get it - though it seemed this platform required at least 5 tags ! Might be mistaken. Anyway, thank you all for your responses: problem was solved.

Comment: No, 5 is the maximum, not the requirement. This is why it asks you to "add up to 5"